# How to trigger Airflow Dag using REST API

Tags: http, go, airflow

I am trying to Trigger Airflow Dags by following https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/api.html this site. They provided a curl command `curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"conf":"{\"key\":\"value\"}"}'` to Trigger Dag. It is working when I execute this command from my Shell.

I tried to call this endpoint in Go `POST /api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs` and I get `400 Bad Request`

How to use `POST /api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs` as `http.POST()` or `http.NewRequest()` in Go?

I tried this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)
func main(){
    body := strings.NewReader(`{"conf":"{\"key\":\"value\"}"}`)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/airflow_sample/dag_runs", body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
}
```

Comment: what is the output you get after curl request? checked server logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

In the main function -

I changed `` body := strings.NewReader(`{"conf":"{\"key\":\"value\"}"}`) ``

To this `` body := strings.NewReader(`{}`) ``

It worked like a Charm.